# Daily ADF output dataset depending on 3 days of input dataset (previous, current, next)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where the output dataset is daily and the input dataset is also daily.Ideally there will be one to one correspondence in this case. For a given day slice , unless that day's slice of input dataset is Ready, that day's slice of output dataset also won't execute.

But the situation is little tricky. The output dataset slice for any given day should only execute when 3 days slices of input dataset are Ready -- Previous Day,  Same Day as Target slice , Next day.

I have created a diagram to illustrate this:-

[image]

The numbers on the line are the days. How do you design a pipeline/dataset for a scenario like this?

Comment: setting delay is not a solution -- as it will not check if 3 days slices of input dataset are Ready or not.

Comment: What are you input and output linked services? You could do this easily with a SQLDB stored procedure call. Or even with an ADF custom activity. But you might struggle if you just have simple copy tasks. Let me know and I'll have a think.

Comment: Input linked services for input and output datasets are of type AzureBlob. And the pipeline activity (there is only one activity) is of type HDInsightHive.

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#model-datasets-with-different-frequencies) gives a hint on how to do this using **startTime** and **endTime** in the pipeline Inputs.

```
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "AzureBlobInput",
        "startTime": "Date.AddDays(SliceStart, -1)",
        "endTime": "Date.AddDays(SliceEnd,  2)"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: this doesn't work , throws an error (pipeline is not deployed at all) due to 3rd line (endTime). If I only specify the startTime part, it works -- but it doesn't work for the endTime line. I also tried changing the number from 2 to 1 for the endTime, still throws an error.